# How to show same ListView for different values?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, globalization

I have a Category List & I want to implement History.Java in my project. which has same fields or parameters as a Category List . Now how to use same `ListView` for history. I am taking a global `boolean` Function . I think it will work. But I want to know any good technique for this. Please tell me? I want to call same Category.Java Class for history & Category List.

Comment: I didn't understand a thing about what you're asking. English please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can also pass 1 dimension array list in Intent

```
Bundle intentbundle = new Bundle();
        intentbundle.putStringArrayList("arrList",arrList);

       intent.putExtras(intentbundle);

       startActivity(intent);
```

> and get values by nex activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
mArrList = extras.getStringArrayList("arrList");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create ListView adapter. Then you'll put some data into the adapter, set it in Listview, and your data will be changed.
Read here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html